# SqlStatementSource expression vs Variable Source Type

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, expression, execute-sql-task

I use SSIS in VS 2017 and SQL Server 2016.

I would like to know what is the difference between the following methods to for setting `SQLStatement`'s value in `Execute SQL Task`:

**First Way**

1. Declare a variable

[image]

2. Configure Execute SQL Task like below

[image]

**Second Way**

1. Declare a variable

[image]

2. Configure Execute SQL Task like below

   [image]

[image]

[image]

In both way, I use variable to assign `SQLStatement`'s value, but in the first one, I set it directly, and in the second one, I use expressions.

Comment: I saw that this question was flag twice as **primarily opinion-based**, i edited the question to remove **what is the best...?** question and ask for difference between both approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There is no better approach, each one has its own use case

1. The first approach can be used if the developer decided to store the whole SQL Command inside a variable.
2. The second can be used if the SQL Command is built based on other variables, such as passing the table name dynamically, or passing parameter because **Execute SQL Task doesn't support parameterized queries**:

   ```
   "SELECT * FROM [" + @[User::SchemaName] + "].[" + @[User::TableName] + "]"
   ```

As i remember, in the old SSIS versions, the first option was not available. Then it is added later *(I think in 2012)* version to facilitate the developer work in case the the whole SQL command is stored inside a variable rather than adding a one variable expression:

```
@[User::strQuery]
```

---

### Official documentation

Based on [Execute SQL Task official documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2017)

*Variable option (1st approach)*

> Set the source to a variable that defines the Transact-SQL statement. Selecting this value displays the dynamic option, SourceVariable.

*Expression use case (2nd approach)*

> When you use an OLE DB connection manager, you cannot use parameterized subqueries because the Execute SQL Task cannot derive parameter information through the OLE DB provider. However, **you can use an expression to concatenate the parameter values into the query string and to set the SqlStatementSource property of the task**.

---

### Variable Evaluated as Expression vs Task Expression

This updated is a reply to the following comment:

> We can have a dynamic value in our variable and set it directly in our SQL Statement.

Both methods will gives the same result, but if you need to use the SQL Statement in different tasks then you should use a variable and use `EvaluateAsExpression` option to avoid writing the Expression multiple time *(Harder to edit the package later)*. Else there is no need to declare a dynamic variable just define the expression inside the Task.

---

Recently I published a detailed article on this topic, you can check it on the following link:

- [SQLShack - Execute a SQL Task in SSIS: SqlStatementSource Expressions vs Variable Source Types](https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-sql-task-in-ssis-sqlstatementsource-expression-vs-variable-source-type/)

Comment: We can ave a dynamic value in our variable and set it directly in our SQL Statement

Comment: What should I use if I need to execute just one time my dynamic query or command (Delete or ...) in my package? 
1 : Variable - set directly variable in EXECUTE SQL TASK
2 : Variable - Add expression on EXECUTE SQL TASK  - Add SqlStatementSource - use the variable

in both approach i have created my command directly in my variable

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi based on the official documentation you have to use the first approach since there is no need to use expressions